# Odata query for outlook rest api

Tags: json, rest, outlook, odata

How to use search and filter in the same query?

```
String url = "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages?$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2016-02-22&$select=Subject,From,Body,ReceivedDateTime&$search=\"subject:(Chris Brown OR Michael Jackson)\"";
```

I need to find all mails with `Subject` having either "Chris Brown" or "Michael Jackson" and mail received date after 22nd Feb, 2016. Also it should have `Subject`, `From`, `Body`, `ReceivedDateTime` in the REST response.

Could anyone please help?

FYI - I am getting output if it has either `filter` or `search`. But when given together, I am getting a "Bad Request" error.

Answer (score 5):

Right now this is not supported. From [Use OData query parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#OdataQueryParams):

> You cannot use **$filter** or **$orderby** in a search request.

So, the only way to do this is to perform a search via a query, and then filter on the client; or vice versa.

**Update**

In this particular case, since subject is filtrable and supposedly you only need an exact subject match (and not 'contains' for example), you can use something along the lines of:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages?$filter=(ReceivedDateTime ge 2016-02-22) and ((subject eq 'Chris Brown') or (subject eq 'Michael Jackson'))
```

Comment: Right, I get that it is not supported.  Looking for a work around that isn't done on the client.  For example - the $search param (https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#UseODataqueryparametersSearchrequests) can take a Received param, is there a way to pass in multiple dates to that, or a "greater than 12/31/2015" date?

Comment: @dave I have updated the answer with a workaround. It will not work with 'contains' though. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking in similar line of using filter. I had tried once which hadn't worked. Let me try again with brackets as you have given

Comment: Actually I was looking for subject contains. So , seems like I have to have my filter logic for subject, not through API

Answer (score 2):

**To answer the original question: yes it is possible**. @roman-pletnev correctly pointed out that you cannot use `$filter` or `$orderby` in a `$search` request. However, you can achieve the desired result using just `$search`.

```
$search="
  (subject:(Chris Brown) OR subject:(Michael Jackson)) 
  AND (received:02/22/2016..10/21/2016)
"
```

Note that extra linebreaks have been included for readability.

Also note that the `received` parameter seems to only work with a single date, or a specific range. I.e. you cannot request "everything after 02/22/2016". Instead you have to input today's date (or a future date?) as the end of the range.

```
received:<date>
received:02/22/2016

received:<start>..<end>
received:02/22/2016..10/21/2016
```

I'm not 100% sure about the date format. I don't know if it's determined by your account's locale or if it's always `MM/DD/YYYY`.

Other variations seem to work as well. However, the documentation for this is very bad and most of the documented syntax for "received" doesn't seem to work. I've filed a support ticket with Microsoft regarding this.

- Some other documented syntax does work, for example `received:today`
- Some documented syntax **does not work**, for example `received:October`

References:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-Outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da
- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-Mail-and-People-in-Outlook-on-the-web-for-business-88108edf-028e-4306-b87e-7400bbb40aa7
- https://msonlinehelpdesk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200561417-Learn-how-to-fine-tune-email-search-results-in-Outlook-and-Outlook-Web-App-OWA-

Comment: GREAT! Couldn't fix this with other ODATA answers. This is what I needed for the `Microsoft365R` package for R :)